# Ruby - Checking if one array key/value is NOT present in another one

Tags: arrays, ruby, compare, each

With ruby, I am trying to look from the first array key[:nb].value, if there is NOT one similar pair in the second one.

Considerate below arrays contain thousands of elements:

```
arr1 = [{"nb"=>"5df54g54df", "active"=>true, "brand"=>"aisle"},{"nb"=>"5jghfj264", "active"=>false, "brand"=>"leg"},{"nb"=>"5qwercv546", "active"=>true, "brand"=>"gem"}]

arr2 = [{"nb"=>"5df54g54df", "active"=>false, "brand"=>"aisle"},{"nb"=>"5jghfj264", "active"=>false, "brand"=>"gem"}]
```

So far I was thinking something like that :

`p (arr1.map(&:nb).find do |nb, val| arr2.map(&:nb)).!Include?(nb && val)`

Would you have a suggestion, please?

After finding those who are not present, for those with similar nb.value, how to highlight the difference they have individually? Tks!

Comment: This is a Hash, so methods to access members won't work, at least unless you want to wrap in OpenStruct. You probably mean `arr1.map { |h| h['nb'] }`.

Comment: If you're doing this on larger lists, consider `.group_by { |h| h['nb'] }` which makes look-ups trivial.

Comment: In coding, "similar" is meaningless. `key` in `key[:nb].value` presumably is an element of `arr1` (a hash), but those hashes do not have a key `:nb`, a symbol, though they do have the key `"nb"`, a string.

Comment: You need to be more clear about your desired result. @Ritesh and I made different assumptions about what that is, and either could be correct. More generally, whenever you give an example in a question always show the desired result (a valid Ruby object), even if you think it should be obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding of the question is as follows: "Find the first element `h` of `arr1` (a hash), such that there is no element `g` of `arr2` (a hash) for which `h["nb"] == g["nb"]` is true".

```
arr1 = [
  {"nb"=>"5df54g54df", "active"=>true, "brand"=>"aisle"},
  {"nb"=>"5jghfj264", "active"=>false, "brand"=>"leg"},
  {"nb"=>"5qwercv546", "active"=>true, "brand"=>"gem"}
]

arr2 = [
  {"nb"=>"5df54g54df", "active"=>false, "brand"=>"aisle"},
  {"nb"=>"5jghfj264", "active"=>false, "brand"=>"gem"}
]
```

```
require 'set'

nbs2 = arr2.each_with_object(Set.new) { |h,st| st << h["nb"] }
  #=> #<Set: {"5df54g54df", "5jghfj264"}>

arr1.find { |h| !nbs2.include?(h["nb"]) }​
  #=> {"nb"=>"5df54g54df", "active"=>true, "brand"=>"aisle"}
```

One could omit the construction of the set `nbs2` and compute

```
arr1.find { |h| !arr2.include?(h["nb"]) }
```

but that requires a linear search through `arr2` for each element `h` of `arr1` that is examined. By contrast, determining whether a set contains a specific element is much faster, with the time required to do so almost independent of the size of the set. The construction of the set itself requires a single pass through `arr2`, with a set lookup and possible addition required when each element of `arr2` is processes.
​

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
arr1 = [
  {"nb"=>"5df54g54df", "active"=>true, "brand"=>"aisle"},
  {"nb"=>"5jghfj264", "active"=>false, "brand"=>"leg"},
  {"nb"=>"5qwercv546", "active"=>true, "brand"=>"gem"}
]

arr2 = [
  {"nb"=>"5df54g54df", "active"=>false, "brand"=>"aisle"},
  {"nb"=>"5jghfj264", "active"=>false, "brand"=>"gem"}
]

# Just create a simple lambda for extracting nb values
 
extract_nb = ->(h) { h['nb'] }

# Using map just apply array intersection operation  
# for finding common key of 'nb'

p arr1.map(&extract_nb) & arr2.map(&extract_nb))
```

optput

```
["5df54g54df", "5jghfj264"]
```